# Usage of 'can't'

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, can-could

Please look at this sentence:
 " I can't **do** the fourth and fifth questions but I have **done** all the other questions" 
is this correct? 
Because in first part present tense is used with the usage of "do" and later part tense is used by using "done". shouldn't be the sentence like this
 "I can't do the fourth and fifth questions but i can do all the other questions"

please clarify. Thank you.

Comment: It rather depends on whether you have already done the other questions or not.  Grammatically, both are correct, but they mean different things.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on when you attempted the questions, it is correct.  If you were given these questions in the classroom and you attempted the questions then and there, it would make sense to say this when you turn in your work.
If you took the questions home and turned in your homework the following day, it would better to say "I couldn't do the fourth and fifth questions"

Answer (score 0):

> "I can't do the fourth and fifth questions but I have done all the other questions"

Yes, this is correct. They two parts don't have to agree as they are two separate statements.  You could equally well say "I can't do the fourth and fifth questions but I will to all the others".

> "I can't do the fourth and fifth questions but I can do all the other questions"

This is also grammatical, but means something different.  The first version says that the speaker has completed the questions.  This form implies that he or she hasn't done yet, but can do in the future. It might even imply that they intend to do so.